# How to access class or record field with the name of the field as a string?

Tags: reflection, chapel

Say you have a record or class:

```
record R {
  var value: int;
}
```

How can I access the field `value` by using the string `"value"`?

For example, in Python, you can access fields using the `getattr` built-in:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

c = C(2)

print(getattr(c, 'value')) # prints 2
```

What would this look like in Chapel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reflection` module's `getField()` and `getFieldRef()` routines provide this capability.  For example, the following program both reads and writes the field 'value' ([TIO](https://tio.run/##jZBBasMwEEX3OsUnm9hQCISsarrtAXwDYX/bAnkcxnJCKTm7M0owIdBFBbMR77/5TDP4M@O6LjNRs4tsUpikck7ZTNqixq8DLl5t4sJPBEmVuzmXv8afGl8QXlEXx9JCVw2JUYqe6TswtoURH9g9oruyrIDDAWc1B9JAdJlBp9OIvZF7iB/Zbrxzm8aKvZts6@lotqwzCB7KjkppiDT9ww0vLfw8h15yIKRXd4Nz0T/eW3flvMQUpMfzUut6Bw)):

```
use Reflection;

record R {
  var value: int;
}

var myR = new R(2);

writeln(getField(myR, "value"));  // print the field from 'myR' named "value"

getFieldRef(myR, "value") = 42;   // get a reference to the field from 'myR' named "value" and assign to it

writeln(myR);                     // print the resulting record
```